# Outer sum, etc. in pytorch

Tags: python, optimization, pytorch, torch

Numpy offers optimized outer operations for any `RxR -> R` function, like `np.multiply.outer` or `np.subtract.outer`, with the behaviour:

```
>>> np.subtract.outer([6, 5, 4], [3, 2, 1])
array([[3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

[Pytorch](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/index.html)  does not seem to offer such a feature (or I have missed it).
What is the best / usual / fastest / cleanest way to do so with torch tensors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the [documenation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html):

> Many PyTorch operations support NumPy Broadcasting Semantics.

An outer subtraction is a broadcasted subtraction from a 2d array to a 1d array, so essentially you can reshape the first array to (3, 1) and then subtract the second array from it:

```
x = torch.Tensor([6, 5, 4])
y = torch.Tensor([3, 2, 1])

x.reshape(-1, 1) - y
#tensor([[3., 4., 5.],
#        [2., 3., 4.],
#        [1., 2., 3.]])
```